# Detect light position on a post-process GLSL shader

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I'm trying to apply a volumetric scattering post-process like the extracted from [Nvidia GPU Gems 3](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-ii-light-and-shadows/chapter-13-volumetric-light-scattering-post-process) now I have something like this:

```
 float4 main(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{  
// Calculate vector from pixel to light source in screen space.  
half2 deltaTexCoord = (texCoord - ScreenLightPos.xy);  
// Divide by number of samples and scale by control factor.  
deltaTexCoord *= 1.0f / NUM_SAMPLES * Density;  
// Store initial sample.  
half3 color = tex2D(frameSampler, texCoord);  
// Set up illumination decay factor.  
half illuminationDecay = 1.0f;  
// Evaluate summation from Equation 3 NUM_SAMPLES iterations.  
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)  
{  
// Step sample location along ray.  
texCoord -= deltaTexCoord;  
// Retrieve sample at new location.  
half3 sample = tex2D(frameSampler, texCoord);  
// Apply sample attenuation scale/decay factors.  
sample *= illuminationDecay * Weight;  
// Accumulate combined color.  
color += sample;  
// Update exponential decay factor.  
illuminationDecay *= Decay;  
}  
// Output final color with a further scale control factor.  
return float4( color * Exposure, 1);  
}
```

But this shader needs as uniform the light pos, I'm thinking if it's possible to detect with a post-process material the position of the light in the screen and how I can do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't use HDR textures in my Graphic Engine and thats the question why I'm asking for that.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is indistinguishable from trying to determine the positions of light sources used to illuminate a scene in a photograph. For some setups it is possible (multiple specular reflections), for others it is impossible (only diffuse illumination of planar surfaces). Anyway, the problem you're trying to solve is a hard problem of computer vision and an ongoing research topic. In any case it's requires a lot of computation and is definitely not the approach you want to go along when rendering a scene.

Comment: Just to put this into perspective:The current approach on CV to solve this problem is is to use probabalistic methods to recreate the scene in a picture, rendering it using modern global illumination method, compare it with the photo and iterate this until a close match is achieved.

Answer (score 2):

The word 'detect' makes it sounds like you're trying estimate the position of a light using information in the framebuffer. There's no good way to do this.

Instead, use [**glUniform**](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml) (in your OpenGL application) to pass the position of the light into the shader. You'll need to declare your light position near the top of the shader:

```
uniform vec2 ScreenLightPos;
```

If the light never moves, you can have its position be a constant in the shader:

```
const vec2 ScreenLightPos = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
```

Or, if the light moves predictably, you can calculate it's position as a function of time:

```
vec2 ScreenLightPos = vec2(sin(time), cos(time));
```

Basically, you need to know where the light is *before* the shader runs. This is true whether you're doing post-processing or surface lighting.

If there is *absolutely no other way*, you might be able to use a [compute shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader) or, worse yet, [pixel reading](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Buffer_reading) to detect bright areas on the framebuffer. This will be horribly slow, and you'll still need to use glUniform to pass the position in once you've figured out where your light is. If even that is somehow not an option, you could use a nested loop in your shader to search through the whole framebuffer for bright spots. I'm not going to explain how to do this or why it's a horrible idea.